# Finding column values for the first and last row in the previous year

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the price history for Google stock in a Google Colab doc, like this:

```
df = pd.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='yahoo', start='08-01-2004')
```

These are open, high, low, close and adjusted close prices for each trading day in the price history. I can create a new column in the DataFrame for the rate of return of the stock over the trailing 12 months like this:

```
df['Trailing 12 month return'] = (df['Adj Close'] - 
  df['Adj Close'].shift(DAYS_TRADING_PER_YEAR)) / 
  df['Adj Close'].shift(DAYS_TRADING_PER_YEAR)
```

But what if what I actually want is one value for rate of the return per year, looking at the return over the previous calendar year? So, for 2015, just find the first trading day (more correctly, the first day for which we have data) in 2014 and the last trading day in 2014 and get the percentage change over that period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Date` is a proper `datetime` column:

1. [**`groupby(df.Date.dt.year)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by year
2. [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) the yearly rates computed from [**`first_valid_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) and [**`last_valid_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html)
3. [**`shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the results to get the previous year

```py
rates = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.year)['Adj Close'].apply(
    lambda g: (g.loc[g.last_valid_index()] - g.loc[g.first_valid_index()]) / g.loc[g.first_valid_index()]
).shift()

# Date
# 2014         NaN
# 2015    0.128019
# 2016    2.232232
# 2017    1.041269
# 2018    0.292042
# 2019    0.154558
# 2020   -0.136102
# 2021    0.396961
# Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

4. Then [**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) these `rates` with `df.Date.dt.year` to create the new column:

```py
df['Previous year rate of return'] = df.Date.dt.year.map(rates)

#            Date   Adj Close  Previous year rate of return
# 0    2014-08-01  166.724074                           NaN
# 1    2014-08-02   69.634211                           NaN
# ...         ...         ...                           ...
# 999  2017-04-26  165.225121                      1.041269
# 1000 2017-04-27   40.165297                      1.041269
# ...         ...         ...                           ...
# 2433 2021-03-30   67.864861                      0.396961
# 2434 2021-03-31   31.408317                      0.396961
```

Comment: This is great but I don't actually want to alter what's in the existing Adj Close column. I'd like this in a new column. It's fine if the same value is repeated over and over for each row in a given year.

Comment: @Eliot Gotcha, answer updated. Basically save those `rates` separately and then `map()` them with `df.Date.dt.year`.